# Как влиять на время отправки датаграммы

Tags: c++, qt, сетевое-программирование

Есть qudpsocket. Есть два массива байт. Мне нужно отправить их в одной датаграмме. Самый простой вариант - копировать два массива в один. Мне он не нравится. Хорошо бы сначала записать в сокет один массив, потом второй а потом отправить датаграмму. Есть ли такой вариант? Как я понимаю датаграмма отправиться сразу же как только закончится запись в сокет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обратите внимание на описание метода [`QAbstractSocket::flush()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#flush):

> In most cases, you do not need to call this function, because `QAbstractSocket` will start sending data automatically once control goes back to the event loop.

что переводится примерно так:

> В большинстве случаев Вам не нужно вызывать эту функцию, потому что `QAbstractSocket` автоматически начнет отправку данных в тот момент, когда управление вернется в цикл событий.

Это в свою очередь означает, что пока происходит выполнение какого-то метода, Вы можете писать во внутренний буфер сокета сколько угодно раз до тех пор, пока метод не завершится (управление не перейдет в цикл событий), либо пока вы явно не вызовите `flush`.